# Excel - get specified rows from every sheet

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have an Excel file with 20 Sheets. Every sheet has 61 rows (one for title and 60 for the data).
I want to create a duplicate file, using only **2nd** and **last** row from every sheet of the original file

So in my new file, I will have 40 rows in one sheet

I have tried PHPExcel, but none of the methods help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PHPExcel: reading the file is a logical first step, then loop through each worksheet and use the removeRow() method to delete the rows you don't want, then save the file.... pretty straightfoward.

```
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("myFileName.xlsx");

// Iterate through each of the 20 worksheets
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    // Remove rows 3-60 (58 rows starting from row 3)
    // This will move the last row (61) up to row 3
    $worksheet->removeRow(3,58);
    // Remove row 1
    $worksheet->removeRow(1);
}

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('myFileName.xlsx');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for a smaller version of the code. But it still gives me 20 sheets. (I reached till here). I **most importantly** want all that sheets to be merged into one. (All data on first sheet).

Comment: Can I create another Object `new PHPExcel();` and add rows in that while iterating in the answer above? If so, how do I add rows? Waiting for your reply...

Comment: Remove the redundant rows, as described above; then use the worksheet's objects toArray() to read the data from each of worksheets 2..20 and fromArray() to copy them to worksheet 1. If styles are different between the worksheets, then you'll need to copy those as well using the getCell(R1)->getStyle method to read and set each style. Finally, use the removeSheetByIndex() method to remove sheets 2..20. Then you can save.

Comment: In your answer, inside the first `foreach`, I am doing this: - `foreach ($worksheet >getRowIterator() as $row) { My Code }`. How do I go ahead. I think you are talking about `My Code` part, where I should use `toArray`. But `$row->toArray()` OR `$worksheet->toArray()`?? Sorry, I am a stranger to PHPExcel. A code snippet for this would be useful

Comment: fromArray() and toArray() are worksheet methods, not row methods... these are detailed in the API docs. Don't use the row iterator if you only want to access just two rows out of 61 (it's a lot of overhead), access them individually